# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function formatUsername() on a non-object in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\global.php on line 146

Tags: php, ajax

I am calling for a function inside of a class on my website. It works on the majority of pages from what I've noticed, however when it tries to do the same thing on AJAX pages (pages that are only accessed through AJAX requests), it seems to error.

```
function formatUsername($id,$link = true,$styles = true, $class = ''){
    global $users;
    return $users->formatUsername($id,$link,$styles,$class);
}
```

is where it is erroring (the return $users->) bit. (global.php)

The actual formatUsername code is: (class.users.php)

```
public function formatUsername($id, $link = true, $styles = true, $class = '')
{
    global $db;
    $dataCheck = $db->dbquery("SELECT id,rank,username FROM users WHERE id = '".$id."' LIMIT 1");

if (mysqli_num_rows($dataCheck) == 0)
{
    return '<s>Unknown User</s>';
}

$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dataCheck);

$prefix = '<a ';
$prefixEnd = '>';
$suffix = '</a>';
$linkStart = '';
$classStart = ' class="';
$classEnd = '"';
$name = $data['username'];

if ($link)
{
    $linkStart .= 'href="'.WWW.'/home/'.clean($data['username']).'" ';
}

if ($styles)
{
    $rank = $data['rank'];
    $rankData = $db->dbquery("SELECT background,name FROM ranks WHERE id = '".$rank."' LIMIT 1");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($rankData) == 1)
    {
        $rankData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rankData);
        $class .= ' sparkle '.$rankData['background'];
    }
}
$final = $prefix . $linkStart . $classStart . $class . $classEnd . $prefixEnd . $name . $suffix;
return clean($final,true,false);
```

}

And the code calling for the request in the AJAX file is:

```
        $usernameForamt = formatUsername($users['id'],true,true);
```

The AJAX file is calling for it from global.php, not from class.users.php.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: are you positive `$users` is available? what happens if you try to print_r($users); after `global $users;`?

Comment: Although I don't know where you're using `$usernameForamt`, am under the impression you may have mispelled it. `$usernameFormat`? Plus, passing 3 parameters instead of 4, where you have 4 in `formatUsername($id, $link = true, $styles = true, $class = '')`

Comment: no it is not mis spelt. Its just a variable in an AJAX file.
I also tried it with 4 parameters and it didn't help.

Comment: @kennypu goatUsers Object ( [userCache:goatUsers:private] => Array ( [16367] => Array ( [newbie_status] => 1 ) ) ) is what happens when I print_r it.

Comment: is goatUsers the name of the class in users.class.php?

Comment: EDIT: I found the problem! The AJAX file had a conflicting $users variable. It was selecting data from the database, but also being used in the global.php file to access the class!

Comment: And this is why we don't use globals >:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @kennypu and @Fred -ii- for their help.

The AJAX file had a conflicting $users variable. It was selecting data from the database, but also being used in the global.php file to access the class!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. +1 for finding it yourself, cheers.